# Op amp level shifting with LT1028

Tags: operational-amplifier, pcb-design, ltspice, level-shifting

I have been using LT1028 in a lot of my projects to amplify bipolar signals before digitization with a (bipolar) analog-to-digital converter.  Now I need to use a 5 V unipolar ADC and am trying to figure out level shifting.

The following amplification scheme works according to simulations with LT spice

(red = op amp output, blue = sine voltage input):

[image]

but unfortunately not in real life, at least in my attempts.  Here is my board layout and some DC voltages that I measured with an oscilloscope.

My question: is the circuit appropriate for the LT1028?  If yes, what else could be going wrong?  If not, then what is a better circuit to use?

[image]

DC potential differences:

- V+ to AGND = 4.15 V (from Li cell)
- output to AGND = 3.29 V.  In theory, should be ~ 2.0 V
- VC2 to AGND = 0.128 V

Solution: see accepted answer.  Below is the oscilloscope trace showing amplification of a 50 mV, 10 kHz sine wave with AD8061 op amp.

[image]

Comment: Are you using the actual LT1028 model in your simulation? That's one of the benefits of using Linear parts

Comment: No, I am using the ideal op amp

Comment: Thats a really expensive level shifter, I believe the Vcc range is higher than 4V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LT1028 is incapable of running from a supply of 4 volts. The minimum supply hinted at in the data sheet is +/- 5 volts. You need to use a rail-to-rail op-amp for use in your schematic. Plenty to choose from.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I missed that in the datasheet.  I'll post back a comment based on findings with a 12 V supply.

Comment: Hold on there - the LT1028 still won't work as you expect. Input common mode range and output voltage swing limitations will scupper that idea - you need to use a rail to rail amplifier or a decent negative and positive supply (min +/- 10 volts for the LT1028). Read the data sheet.

Comment: Can you also suggest other opamps to read about, given that I want to amplify a signal for 0-5 V ADC?  I need similar noise performance and gain bandwidth as LT1028.

Comment: No I can't without you telling me who your distibutors are, what country you are in, what budget you desire and what performances you expect from your circuit. Do you see the issue I have? PS I'm not going down that road of course but if you want to do some research and find one I'll be happy to review it. Having said that I have used the ADA4528 in a similar circuit but don't bitch if it's too costly for you.

Comment: Yes sure, I can do the searching.  Thanks for the hints.

Comment: And, in your own time you can thank me without using words but by marking the answer as accepted.

Comment: Indeed, a 5 V rail-rail opamp did the job and there are several available.  I used AD8061 which came in the same SO-8 package and I do not need to make a new PCB.  Result appended to the main question.